# Using events within a JS library without them being overwritten

Tags: javascript, events

I'm creating a small library of custom functions which I regularly use so I don't need to redefine them every time I start a new project. In the library I need to update a value on the URL hash change so need to use `window.onhashchange`.

The problem is that any time I need to use `window.onhashchange` outside of the library it overwrites the functionality provided by the library. Is there any way around this?

Comment: how are you trying to use multiple functions for window.onhashchange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use addEventListener to use multiple functionality

```
  function customFunction(args){
      console.log("custome override");
  }

  function libHashChange(args){
      console.log("library methods");
  }

  window.addEventListener("hashchange", libHashChange);
  window.addEventListener("hashchange", customFunction);
```

Comment: As per knowledge you cannot, You can suggest some guidelines to your end users to use addEventListeners/ attach events but cannot stop them overriding any thing in the their code.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `window.addEventListener`:

```
function myListener(evt) {
  console.log(evt);
}

// before
window.onhashchange = myListener;

// after
window.addEventListener('hashchange', myListener);
```

To remove a previously added listener: `window.removeEventListener(myListener);`